# Redirect after action CREATE_SUCCES

Tags: angular, ngrx

I've got a component to create a new record... When submitting my form, i dispatch a CREATE action.

In the OnInit of this component i've got an ActionsSubject subscription to
catch the completion of the CREATE action. On this completion i redirect to the overview component.

This works fine the first time i insert a record, but when trying to add a  second record, the actionssubject completion subscriptions gets hit immediatly as soon as i'm back on the create component and i get redirected back to the overview.

```
redirectSub: Subscription;

constructor(
  private store: Store<fromRoot.State>,
  private router: Router,
  private actionsSubject: ActionsSubject
) { }


ngOnInit() {
  this.redirectSub = this.actionsSubject.asObservable().pipe(
    ofType(ContactsActionTypes.CREATE_SUCCESS)
  ).subscribe(
    (action: CreateSuccess) => this.router.navigate(['/contacts', action.payload.id])
  );
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.redirectSub.unsubscribe();
}

submitted(subspecialisatie: SubSpecialisatie) {
  this.store.dispatch(new Create(subspecialisatie));
}




@Effect()
create$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
ofType(SubSpecialisatiesActionTypes.CREATE),
map((action: Create) => action.payload),
switchMap((subspecialisatie) => this.subspecialisatieService.createSubSpecialisatie(subspecialisatie)),
map((createdSubSpecialisatie: SubSpecialisatie) => new CreateSuccess(createdSubSpecialisatie))
);
```

I should by able to come back to the create component without being redirected immediatly...

Comment: Can you add this.actionsSubject declaration to code listing, please?

Comment: i've updated the code...

Comment: Thanks, check my answer

Answer (score 3):

I think i got what you are doing wrong, you are **listening to the action** and handling it **at component**, which is not good. You **should listen to actions** **only at reducers** (if it's synchronous handler + it produces new state) or **effects** (if it's asynchronous handler, or just side activity).
So you can listen to **CREATE_SUCCESS** at **Effects** and **do reroute there**. For example:

```
constructor(
   ...,
   private router: Router,
   ...
) { }

@Effect({ dispatch: false })
createSuccess$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
   ofType(SubSpecialisatiesActionTypes.CREATE_SUCCESS),
   tap((action) => this.router.navigate(['/contacts', action.payload.id]))
);
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: this sounds like a not extensible solution. what if I want to have different route prefixes depending on component witch dispatched action?

Comment: I am not experienced with NGRX yet, but I think you should be very careful when resuing action. Maybe using another action is the better option for that. 
Think of an action like an event that can happen.

Answer (score 0):

I've got it. The ActionsSubject stores the latest action. Even when destroying the subscription.

I've changed it to a ScannedActionsSubject and now all works fine.